# Is Azure Blob Storage Stats request Billable?

Tags: azure

If I send request to Azure Blob and get listing of Blobs and Files in my Application is this request is billable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's [`billable`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/), but if you consider the amount it's very negligible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does means of the square and cube on (10,000)

Comment: The little number on top is a footnote, not squared.